# Ansible loop through list to build folder structure

Tags: list, loops, ansible, path, structure

i got the following lists:

```
vars:

  - sftp_users:

    - name: user1

      authorized: [user1.pub]

      append: True

      home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1

      sftp_directories:

      - folder1

      - folder2

    - name: user2

      authorized: [user2.pub]

      append: True

      home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2

      sftp_directories:

      - folder3

  - sftp_subdirectories:

    - source

    - processed

    - rejected
```

And i would like to generate the following structure for each user with its "sftp_directories" and some common "sftp_subdirectories" like this

```
/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/source

/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/processed

/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/rejected

/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/source

/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/processed

/cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/rejected

/cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/source

/cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/processed

/cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/rejected
```

How can I achieve this the best.

I have tried it with with_nested and with_subelements. Couldn't achieve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below Jinja

```yaml
  sublist: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for user in sftp_users %}
    {% for dir in user.sftp_directories %}
    {% for subdir in sftp_subdirectories %}
    - {{ user.home }}/{{ dir }}/{{ subdir }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

will create the list

```yaml
  sublist:
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/source
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/processed
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/rejected
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/source
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/processed
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/rejected
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/source
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/processed
  - /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/rejected
```

If you want to iterate the structure combine the lists

```yaml
  subdirs: "{{ sftp_users|
               map(attribute='sftp_directories')|
               map('product', sftp_subdirectories)|
               map('map', 'join', '/')|
               map('community.general.dict_kv', 'subdirs') }}"
  sftp_subdirs: "{{ sftp_users|zip(subdirs)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  sftp_subdirs:
  - append: true
    authorized:
    - user1.pub
    home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1
    name: user1
    sftp_directories:
    - folder1
    - folder2
    subdirs:
    - folder1/source
    - folder1/processed
    - folder1/rejected
    - folder2/source
    - folder2/processed
    - folder2/rejected
  - append: true
    authorized:
    - user2.pub
    home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2
    name: user2
    sftp_directories:
    - folder3
    subdirs:
    - folder3/source
    - folder3/processed
    - folder3/rejected
```

Now, you can iterate the list with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.home }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ sftp_subdirs|subelements('subdirs') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/source
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/processed
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/rejected
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/source
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/processed
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/rejected
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/source
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/processed
  msg: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/rejected
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    sftp_users:
      - append: true
        authorized: [user1.pub]
        home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1
        name: user1
        sftp_directories: [folder1, folder2]
      - append: true
        authorized: [user2.pub]
        home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2
        name: user2
        sftp_directories: [folder3]
    sftp_subdirectories: [source, processed, rejected]

    subdirs: "{{ sftp_users|
                 map(attribute='sftp_directories')|
                 map('product', sftp_subdirectories)|
                 map('map', 'join', '/')|
                 map('community.general.dict_kv', 'subdirs') }}"
    sftp_subdirs: "{{ sftp_users|zip(subdirs)|map('combine') }}"
    sublist: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for user in sftp_users %}
      {% for dir in user.sftp_directories %}
      {% for subdir in sftp_subdirectories %}
      - {{ user.home }}/{{ dir }}/{{ subdir }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: subdirs
    - debug:
        var: sublist
    - debug:
        var: sftp_subdirs

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.home }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ sftp_subdirs|subelements('subdirs') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
      tags: loop
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve your requirement. The below playbook is a bit far-fetched but gives the result you expect using only ansible and without requiring supplementary `set_facts` and loop.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sftp_users:
      - name: user1
        authorized: [user1.pub]
        append: True
        home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user1
        sftp_directories:
          - folder1
          - folder2
      - name: user2
        authorized: [user2.pub]
        append: True
        home: /cdrstorage/sftp/user2
        sftp_directories:
          - folder3
    sftp_subdirectories:
      - source
      - processed
      - rejected

    _homes: "{{ ['home: '] | product(sftp_users | map(attribute='home')) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"
    _dirs: "{{ ['subdirs: '] 
      | product(
        sftp_users | map(attribute='sftp_directories')
        | map('product', sftp_subdirectories) | map('map', 'join', '/')
      )
      | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"

    _all_info: "{{ _homes | zip(_dirs) | map('combine') | subelements('subdirs') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Example task
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "I would create {{ item.0.home }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ _all_info }}"
```

This gives (you can debug intermediate vars to study the solution):

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Example task] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder1/source']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/source"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder1/processed']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/processed"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder1/rejected']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder1/rejected"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder2/source']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/source"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder2/processed']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/processed"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user1', 'subdirs': ['folder1/source', 'folder1/processed', 'folder1/rejected', 'folder2/source', 'folder2/processed', 'folder2/rejected']}, 'folder2/rejected']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user1/folder2/rejected"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user2', 'subdirs': ['folder3/source', 'folder3/processed', 'folder3/rejected']}, 'folder3/source']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/source"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user2', 'subdirs': ['folder3/source', 'folder3/processed', 'folder3/rejected']}, 'folder3/processed']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/processed"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'home': '/cdrstorage/sftp/user2', 'subdirs': ['folder3/source', 'folder3/processed', 'folder3/rejected']}, 'folder3/rejected']) => {
    "msg": "I would create /cdrstorage/sftp/user2/folder3/rejected"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```